# Do While Loop: Loop without do error

Tags: vba, excel

The below code is providing a "Loop without do error" while I have my very simple do while statement. Code runs without it, however will not loop through the 100 rows I am extracting data from.

Its clear that the issue is a result of the readystate dowhile (as code will run if I comment this out), but I am not sure of the mechanics of this working without this for IE.

Is anyone able to explain what additional(?) line of code I need to add to stop this error?

```
Do While i < 100

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .Navigate URLStart
        .Visible = True
        Do While .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        Set doc = ie.Document

        With doc
            LicenceNO = "whatever"
            ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value = LicenceNO
            LicenceName = "whatever"
            ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i).Value = LicenceName
            BusinessAddress = "whatever"
            ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Value = BusinessAddress
            AATOCategory = "whatever"
            ActiveSheet.Range("F" & i).Value = AATOCategory
        End With

        i = i + 1

Loop
```

Thanks all!

Comment: You haven't closed your `With ie` block.

Comment: There is no End With to close the With ie block.

Comment: This is a good example of how **uniform indentation and spacing** helps highlight coding mistakes.  (I fixed the indentation and now it's easier to see the issue.) [I didn't see the answer when I wrote this, but @Olly was on it already!]

Comment: unrelated, note that your loop will run until `99`, not until `100`. If you need to go to `100` then use `<=` instead of `<`

Comment: Right you all are, I had my end with outside my loop. I moved it back inside the loop and its now working fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With consistent indenting, you can see the missing `End With`:

```
Do While i < 100

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .Navigate URLStart
        .Visible = True
        Do While .ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set doc = ie.Document

        With doc
            LicenceNO = "whatever"
            ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value = LicenceNO
            LicenceName = "whatever"
            ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i).Value = LicenceName
            BusinessAddress = "whatever"
            ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Value = BusinessAddress
            AATOCategory = "whatever"
            ActiveSheet.Range("F" & i).Value = AATOCategory
        End With

        i = i + 1

    'This line missing:
    End With

Loop
```